# "If anyone knows" or "Does anyone know"?

Tags: verb-forms

I am a native English speaker who is living abroad and as such I get many questions about English that I find hard to answer having never studied English grammar.

One of them is the following:

- Does anyone *know*
- If anyone *knows*

Why does the verb *"to know"* change depending on whether the question starts with *"does"* or *"if"*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to English grammar, if an auxiliary verb (*"to do"*, in this case) is present,  it is the only one that conjugates, while the main verb remains in the bare infinitive form.

The sentence with *"if"* does not have an auxiliary verb, so in that case the verb *"know"* conjugates; while in the sentence with *"does"*, *"know"* stays in the infinitive form. Consider:

> Anyone *knows*; if anyone *knows*; maybe anyone *knows*;
>   Anyone *does* not know;
>   *Does* anyone know?;
>   Anyone *does* know;

Although the form "subject + *does* + verb" is not popular, it is pretty grammatical. This form is principally used to emphasize a fact, particularly to contradict a previous assertion, with emphasis on *"does"*:

> "I don't think anyone knows."
>   "This can't be. Someone **does** know!"*

Comment: You're on the right track, but the choice between the two is determined by meaning, not popularity. "Does anyone know what we're having for dinner?" is a question. "If anyone knows what we're having for dinner, could you please let me know?" is a request.

Comment: @Martha Thank you for pointing this out. I fixed the ambiguous statement. "Latter form" was about "subject + does + verb" from my list, not about "does anyone know" versus "if anyone knows"

Comment: +1 I would reword the last sentence: The form "subject" + *does* + verb is principally used to emphasize a fact especially particularly to contradict a previous assertion. "Someone **does** know", with emphasize on *does*.